# How to convert decimals correctly after calculation

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the below problem, how to make it appear 0.00004 as string after multiplication?

```
$v = -0.00004;
$v = $v * -1;
echo $v; // 4.0E-5
```

**Long story**

As a result I need to save into MySQL database but no problem with that because I use below query:

```
$sql_insert = $conn->prepare("insert into tbl_transaction (amount) values ($v)");
```

However when I output to my HTML it showing `4.0E-5`. I tried to use number_format but in some cases the decimals will go far more than this so it is not a choice.

Comment: Have a look at the number_format() function

Comment: MySQL understands exponential format, what's wrong with `4.0e-5`?

Comment: @Barmar Problem is I need to display `0.00004` correctly in HTML

Comment: Then why does the question say the problem is with saving it into the database?

Comment: Use `number_format` with a large number of digits, e.g. `number_format($v, 20)`

Comment: Are you kidding? I said no problem on saving that. It's problem when I output to HTML..

Comment: I see, I misread.

Comment: number_format($v,20) return 0.00004000000000000000; Not ideal man :(

Comment: The database is irrelevant to this problem, take it out of the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161760/discussion-between-isaac-and-barmar).

Comment: This is not a database problem, this is a displaying things *from* the database problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
echo sprintf('%f', $v);
```

Or:

```
$b = sprintf('%f', $v);
echo $b;
```

Comment: Cant, it is returning `0.000040`.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below.

```
$v = -0.00004;
$v = $v * -1;
echo number_format($v, 5);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting the number with the desired precision you need to strip the trailing zeros.

This should do the trick:

```
$v = -0.00004;
$v = number_format($v * -1, 20);
print rtrim($v, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `var_dump($v)` after the first assignment, you'll see that the "problem" is NOT the calculation.

```
$v = -0.00004;
var_dump($v);  //float(-4.0E-5)
```

[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) can be used to return a formatted version of your value.  You can get the length of the string value, and pass that to number_format.

```
var_dump(number_format($v,strlen(strval($v)))); // string(10) "-0.0000400"
```

So, your code would be:

```
$v = -0.00004;
$v = $v * -1;
$v = number_format($v,strlen(strval($v)));
echo $v  //0.000040
```

You don't need to use number_format until you're ready to display the value because the exponential number is the same value as the formatted / decimal number.